# How to get data to the watch webhook, in push notification, without SSL certificate, during development

Tags: c#-4.0, push-notification, ssl-certificate, google-calendar-api

I want to check the push notification in google calendar api.
I post the watch request and returned OK, but the changes didn't send the webhook.
Probably because I do not have an SSL certified, how can I test this function while developing?